# Combining 2 one columns statements into 1 two column statement

Tags: sql-server-2005

Let say I have two select statements (This is  just an example. Data could be text also):

```
 S1        S2
| 1 |    | a |
| 2 |    | b |  
| 3 |    | c |
| 4 |    | d |
| 5 |    | e |
```

How can I "glue" them together into one statement but with one column each like this:

```
 S1         S2          S3
| 1 |     | a |     | 1   a |
| 2 |     | b |     | 2   b |  
| 3 |  +  | c |  =  | 3   c |  
| 4 |     | d |     | 4   d |
| 5 |     | e |     | 5   e |
```

And if that is even possible, will it be resistant to null or empty statements like this?:

```
 S1         S2           S3
| 1 |     |NULL|     | 1  NULL|
| 2 |                | 2  NULL|
| 3 |  +          =  | 3  NULL|
| 4 |                | 4  NULL|
| 5 |                | 5  NULL|
```

The two statements have no keys, but do belong to each other row wise (unless one of them is null).

I know this can be done using while loops, cursors and temp tables. The problem is I need this to be fast and don't use that many resources, because this statement will be fired a lot. Maybe some of you know a neat trick to achieve this or have a suggestion how solve it?

**What is this used for?:**
What this solution is for is a log system that need to take the trigger tables UPDATED and INSERTED, translate each row into a XML part and put them into a temporary table with the XML values or null (depending on the changed action on that particular table).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do the two result sets come from the `updated` and `inserted` tables? If so, it should be possible to link them directly on the source table key by including it in the query.

Comment: @EdHarper What do you mean by table key? If you talk about the table primary key then that wont work in my situation as the change could be the actual primary key that is changing.

Comment: The first bit would be an inner join on Row_number, outer join with row_number() is effectively impossible without some other criteria (e.g. S2 = S1 * 10) in your example, in which case, you don't need row_number in the first place.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson The sample in the question is just an example. The values will be anything. Numbers, texts, and bits. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: @evilfish - if the prmary key is mutable then it's a poor choice of primary key. Is there scope to consider switching to an immutable surrogate primary key (such as an identity column), which would make what you're tring to do much easier?

Comment: @EdHarper I'm afraid not. I've done a bit of digging and my solution might not be eligible at all to the purpose i'm using it for. My solution assumes that the rows from INSERTED and the rows from DELETED, if we talk about an update action, return same rows in the same order relative to each other. This however, is not guaranteed. I'm currently discussing this issue with some co-workers think up a new solution.

Comment: @evilfish, row 1 in table A = rowN in Table B, you can do, somehow. But if you can't give us a rule we can't translate it into Sql.

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understand the question but If you want to combine two columns into one you can just use

```
SELECT CONCAT(ColumnA, ColumnB) AS ColumnZ
FROM Table
```

Not sure if sql 2005 supports the CONCAT method though, but if not you will need to use syntax such as (expression + expression)

Comment: The two select statement comes from two separate tables. And CONCAT is not a supported 2005 function.

Comment: then try a select into statement. first insert your 2 selects int 2 table variables and try something like this
    SELECT sel1 + sel2 AS 'sel3' into Table3
    FROM @table1
  with a  INNER JOIN

Comment: or even better put both selects in one table with two columns and then use a select into statement like above

Comment: Joins is not possible. I have no key to join on.

Comment: First insert the two selects into one table variable

DECLARE @tempTable TABLE
(
  sel1 varchar(255),
  sel2 varchar(255)
)
INSERT INTO tempTable (sel1, sel2)
then select it like this
SELECT sel1 + sel2 AS 'sel3' FROM tempTable

Comment: Ohh you thought the same thing as Tony. The sample in the question is not an actual table of mine. It's a pure example the could be text instead. I was not clear about that and have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your other comments perhaps something like this might help.

```
Select Row_Number() Over(Order By S1.Value) as LeftRow, S1.Value as LeftValue Into #TempTable
Select LeftRow, LeftValue, RightRow, RightValue From #TempTable
Inner Join (Select Row_Number() Over(Order By S2.Value) as RightRow, S2.Value as RightValue) rightTable
On LeftRow = RightRow
Drop Table #TempTable
```

maybe ?